# How did a 1-rep user make a question Community Wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

R.E: [What is the exact use of a MAC address?](https://superuser.com/questions/623511/what-is-the-exact-use-of-a-mac-address)

According to [the revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/623511/revisions) of the question, it was made Community Wiki by a user called [tigerden](https://superuser.com/users/240466/tigerden); who, it turns out;

- Has 1 rep
- Has been registered for 3 days
- Has no prior activity on Super User... [at all](https://superuser.com/users/240466/tigerden?tab=activity&sort=all).

... so what gives him "the power" to make the post Community Wiki?

Comment: He probably added the final answer that pushed the entire question and all its answers into wiki. Although I don't see 15 answers, I presume some of them got deleted since then.

Comment: @Mysticial: I thought that at first, but don't questions get the annotation "Post Made Community Wiki by question having more than X answers" e.g. http://superuser.com/posts/565883/revisions in that case?

Comment: @Mysticial: Presumably, considering tigerden's answer is not visible. FWIW, the same thing happened [on this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/189515/revisions) and I was baffled why it listed the user who posted the 30th answer. But now it appears that's been fixed? Don't know when that history event changed... I just remember being baffled by it.

Comment: @animuson I talked to the devs about this, and this is a bit of an edge case. The reason the revision history attributes this to a person rather than the normal notice is because the check for that notice runs live, it's not recorded historically. Since there are not currently more than 15 answers, the notice doesn't apply. Short answer: Our system is weird, and we can probably fix it eventually even though it should be a rare occurrence.

Answer (score 7):

Mysticial's assessment is correct. Tigerden is attributed with "making" the post community wiki because that user posted the 16th answer (some of which are now deleted, including tigerden's). Questions on Super User which [generate more than 15 answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/166017) are automatically converted to community wiki.

The post being made community wiki shouldn't be attributed to the user who broke the threshold for answers; that's a bug that I'll have someone look into.

Comment: Which begs the question: Shouldn't the question be unwikied if deleted answers contributed to auto-wiki? What stops someone from spamming answers with the intention to wikify a question?

Comment: Spamming answers to wikify a question... you gave me an idea there...

Comment: @Mysticial: [only the rate-limits on answer creation and deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143927/what-is-the-purpose-of-uservoice)

Comment: @Shog9 Wow, you look like you had some fun there...

Comment: Also some waffles. Ah, the days before SO got all highfalutin and switched to croissants...